# ObjectInput- and OutputStream: send a changed object second time

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm writing a client-server application, and I need to send an object to the client sometimes.
So I tried this:

Server side:

```
    ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    s = ss.accept();

    ize = new HashMap<>();
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ize.put("ize", new TileSprite(1, 2, 3, 4, "tile"));
    oos.writeObject(ize);
    System.out.println(ize.get("ize").getX());

    //oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ize.get("ize").setX(2);
    oos.writeObject(ize);
    System.out.println(ize.get("ize").getX());
```

Client side:

```
    s = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    ize = (HashMap<String, GeneralSprite>) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(ize.get("ize").getX());

    //ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    ize = (HashMap<String, GeneralSprite>) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(ize.get("ize").getX());
```

Unless I remove the comment from the 2 reinitialization, I never get the right values.  I tried it some ways, but the outcome was nearly always the same: Sometimes I got some error, or just the same old value for x (1 instead of 2 at the second time).

I don't think reinitializing is the right way to do this, so I tried ObjectOutputStream.reset() method, but it didn't work either.

Comment: reset() will work if used correctly.

Comment: Strange, last time it didn't work. Now its working. Maybe I cleaned the project. Anyway thanks.